# How to model state sharing between classes/modules in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have 2 Python classes that are in separate modules. One class maintains a state attribute that the other needs to observe and use when certain actions are handled.

Right now, I'm using an event-based approach to allow the second class to detect when the state changes in the first class and update its reference to the state accordingly. But I feel this approach is not the best way to do this as it makes maintaining and understanding the code difficult.

So here's an example of what I'm doing right now.

```py
# module 1

class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
      self.state = "INITIAL_STATE"

   def change_state(self, new_state):
      self.state = new_state
      EventManager.fire_event("state_changed", self.state)

# module 2

class Bar:
   def __init__(self):
      self.state = "INITIAL_STATE"

   def handle_state_change_event(self, new_state):
      self.state = new_state

   # how this state is used in this class
   def take_action(self):
      if self.state == "INITIAL_STATE":
         print("action1")
      elif self.state == "CONFIRMED":
         print("action2)
      # And so on
```

I want to see if anyone can suggest a better approach/design pattern to model this.

Note: The second class doesn't change the state, only use the value of the state to decide which action to take

Comment: I generally use a `shared_data` module that is imported by all other modules and holds said shared data.

Comment: One thing up front: It's not the classes that share state but instances of those classes that are connected to each other, or? That part isn't clear. Generally, reacting to such changes is done using the Monitor Pattern. Emitting events is similar, just slightly more general and less directed, but it's useable too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry for the confusion. It's the instances sharing state. With monitor pattern, do I have to maintain the state outside both classes and pass them during instance creation time?